# How is the synchronized method on AnyRef implemented?

Tags: scala, concurrency

In Scala, there's a synchronized method on AnyRef which lets you synchronize on any object that extends AnyRef.  However, it's abstract on AnyRef, and I couldn't figure out how it worked from grepping the scala source.  It seems like it works by exploiting the synchronized keyword in Java.  Is that the case?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

1) `AnyRef.synchronized` is a magic method that doesn't exist in source code, but is injected into the compiler's symbol table on every startup of the compiler: [Definitions.scala](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/54cb6af7dbcf630a4f57e98f0099d77dd3b36693/src/reflect/scala/reflect/internal/Definitions.scala#L913).  There's a number of magic methods and classes, by the way ([Definitions.scala](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/8b41240f3d532c470112d7bf1f409badac4d56aa/src/reflect/scala/reflect/internal/Definitions.scala#L1099)).

2) If a method is wrapped in `this.synchronized`, the wrapping is dropped, and the method is internally annotated with a `SYNCHRONIZED` flag ([UnCurry.scala](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/54cb6af7dbcf630a4f57e98f0099d77dd3b36693/src/compiler/scala/tools/nsc/transform/UnCurry.scala#L534)), which is then mapped to JVM's `ACC_SYNCHRONIZED method access flag ([GenASM.scala](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/54cb6af7dbcf630a4f57e98f0099d77dd3b36693/src/compiler/scala/tools/nsc/backend/jvm/GenASM.scala#L238)).

3) Other calls to `synchronized` are mapped onto the backend's primitive `SYNCHRONIZED` ([backend/ScalaPrimitives.scala](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/54cb6af7dbcf630a4f57e98f0099d77dd3b36693/src/compiler/scala/tools/nsc/backend/ScalaPrimitives.scala#L210)), which is later lowered into monitorenter/monitorexit ([GenICode.scala #1](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/54cb6af7dbcf630a4f57e98f0099d77dd3b36693/src/compiler/scala/tools/nsc/backend/icode/GenICode.scala#L460), [GenICode.scala #2](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/54cb6af7dbcf630a4f57e98f0099d77dd3b36693/src/compiler/scala/tools/nsc/backend/icode/GenICode.scala#L309)).

Answer (score 9):

Just to add to the answer from Eugene, who knows the compiler by heart, here is a little scala console session.

The bottom line: the generated code is exactly identical to what you would get in java. There is no closure generated for the synchronized { ... } and not even a method call. Just a try/catch where at the beginning of the try there is a monitorenter bytecode (3) and both in the normal exit (9) an in the catch exit (12) there is a monitorexit. **So there is no overhead involved in using synchronized in scala vs using it in java**.

Note that most people agree that having dangerous low level thread synchronization constructs on every object is generally considered a bad idea that was only done for java compatibility.

```
scala> class Test { def test { this.synchronized { } } }
defined class Test

scala> :javap -c Test
Compiled from "<console>"
public class Test extends java.lang.Object implements scala.ScalaObject{
public void test();
  Code:
   0:   aload_0
   1:   dup
   2:   astore_1
   3:   monitorenter
   4:   getstatic   #12; //Field scala/runtime/BoxedUnit.UNIT:Lscala/runtime/BoxedUnit;
   7:   pop
   8:   aload_1
   9:   monitorexit
   10:  return
   11:  aload_1
   12:  monitorexit
   13:  athrow
  Exception table:
   from   to  target type
     4    10    11   any
```