# How to create a synchronized object method in scala

Tags: scala, synchronization

Does scala support synchronized object (/static) methods?  I am looking for:

```
synchronized def myObjectMethod(): <SomeReturnType> = {
.. 
 }
```

If this were not supported, what is the equivalent in scala ?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`synchronized` in scala is just a method<sup>1</sup>. So you can do

```
def myObjectMethod: SomeReturnType = synchronized {
  // stuff
}
```

---

<sub>It's actually a special method injected by the compiler, more details here: [How is the synchronized method on AnyRef implemented?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17627006/how-is-the-synchronized-method-on-anyref-implemented)</sub>

Comment: I have a method with Try {} , how can use synchronuzed ?

Comment: Doesn't `synchronized` synchronize with `this`? So if I have `def foo = synchronized{ /* stuff */}; def bar = synchronized{ /* other stuff */ }`, will I be able to run the two concurrently (i.e., `foo` and `bar` can run at same time but one at most copy of each)