# How does synchronization work in this scala example?

Tags: java, scala, synchronization, synchronized

I'm new to scala and I'm trying to get used to the language.  I was looking for an equivalent to the following Java synchronisation technique.

```
private final Map<String, Future<Boolean>> requestMap = new HashMap<>();

public void updateMap(String key) {
    synchronized(requestMap) {
        // update contents of requestMap
    }
}
```

I think the syntax below is the Scala equivalent of the Java above.

```
private val requestMap = new mutable.LinkedHashMap[String, Future[Boolean]]

def updateMap(key: String): Unit = {
    requestMap.synchronized {
        // update contents of requestMap
    }
}
```

What I'm trying to achieve here is ensuring that only one thread can manipulate the `requestMap` object at any given time in the `updateMap` method.  I want to know are the two examples above equivalent and where can I find this Scala usage of `synchronized` documented?

Comment: There is no difference for `synchronized`, as it's a binding over the JVM one: Scala `foo.synchronized { .. }` = `synchronized(foo) { .. }`

Comment: OK, I thought as much but couldn't find it documented.  Can you tell me where I should look?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right, these are equivalent:

```
//Java
synchronized(foo) { statements ... }

//Scala
foo.synchronized { statements ... }
```

In scala, `synchronized` is a library construct (although a *synthetic* one) - that is, it is [a method on `AnyRef`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/AnyRef.html#synchronized[T0](x$1:=>T0):T0)

Comment: Ah, I also found a this SO question which shows how this method is implemented: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17627006/how-is-the-synchronized-method-on-anyref-implemented

Answer (score 0):

Referring to the same discussion can we have something like this and will it make the code inside *AnyRef*.synchronized, thread safe?

```
Object abc {
 ...
    *AnyRef*.synchronized{
       val ff = new FunClass()
       ff.displayTs()
    }

}

class FunClass() {
  def displayTs(): Unit{
    println(timestamp)
  }
}

...
}
```